# Cypress UI automated login with Keycloak fails

Tags: javascript, selenium, single-sign-on, keycloak, cypress

I am attempting to automate an e-commerce store front using [Cypress](https://www.cypress.io/) but I'm running into an issue with login.

The auth and identity tool being used is [keycloak](https://www.keycloak.org/) and the Cypress test is unable to login or register successfully. The flow is as follows: visit siteundertest.com > Click login/register > redirects to keycloak > enter valid login info > click login. Expected result: Login is successful and user is redirected to authenticated home page (siteundertest.com). Actual: An error occurred processing your request.

Notes:

- This test works using Selenium
- POST requests are not enabled for keycloak in the current domain (a decision out of my control) so I can't bypass login/register with an API call: [Bypass UI Login using Cypress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51878136/bypass-ui-login-using-cypress)
- I suspect a cookie/header information is lost but I'm not sure how to determine what information needs to be provided with Cypress
- I have tried disabling web security in cypress.json (config) and various other suggestions: [Unable to signup using Keycloak through Cypress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54145874/unable-to-signup-using-keycloak-through-cypress)
- Error occurs in both headless (electron) and Chrome/FF/Edge
- Manual login works fine and various user accounts were used
- Same error occurs when Cypress clicks the keycloak registration button
- Have tried also tried:
  `Cypress.Cookies.preserveOnce('session_id', 'remember_token') Cypress.Cookies.preserveOnce('session_code', 'remember_token') Cypress.Cookies.preserveOnce('client_id', 'remember_token') Cypress.Cookies.preserveOnce('clientsession')`
  but I will admit I'm running a bit blind here so I''m trying anything.

Courtesy of a helpful dev I was able to get some information from keycloak with regards to cookies, Cypress > Selenium > Manual Web:
[image]

The test:

```js
describe('Login to Keycloak with Email', function(){ 

  before(function () {
    cy.fixture('logindata').then(function (data) {
      this.data = data;           
    })
  })

  it('Open Homepage', function(){
    cy.visit(this.data.OccTestHmepageUrl)
  })
 
  it('Click Log In', function(){
   cy.get('[data-bind="visible: !(loggedInUserName() && (loggedIn() || isUserSessionExpired()))"] > #CC-loginHeader-login').click()
  });
  
  it('Verify Redirect to Keycloak', function(){
    cy.get('.auth-land-page > :nth-child(1) > .text-center')
  });

  it('Click login button', function(){
    cy.get('.emailLogin > .auth-button-content').click()    
  })

  it('Enter valid email address', function(){
    cy.fixture('logindata').then(function (data) {
    this.data = data;
    cy.get('#emailUsername')
    .type(this.data.LoginEmail)}
    )}
  )

  it('Enter valid password', function(){
    cy.fixture('logindata').then(function (data) {
      this.data = data;
      cy.get('#password')
      .type(this.data.LoginPassword)}
      )}
    )

  it('Click login button', function(){
    cy.get('#loginBtn').click()
    // Error occurs here
  })

  it('Verify successful login', function(){
    //Redirect fails
    cy.get('#CC-loginHeader-logout')
    })
  })
```

Thanks in advance to whomever can help!

Comment: Have you solved this problem already?  Would you share the solution?

Answer (score 0):

The problem could be caused by the split login. Maybe you could try and put the whole login into one "it".
Just for testing purposes I split my working login test into several tests and then it didn't work, so I assume it should be one test.
Maybe you found a fix or the topic isn't still important to you, since it has been asked 8 months ago :)
But I would be interested in hearing from you, if this fixes your problem, or if it doesn't change a thing, or if you found another way to make it work.

New code could look like this:

```js
describe('Login to Keycloak with Email', function () {

  before(function () {
    cy.fixture('logindata').then(function (data) {
      this.data = data;
    })
  })

  it('Login', function () {
    cy.visit(this.data.OccTestHmepageUrl)
    cy.get(
        '[data-bind="visible: !(loggedInUserName() && (loggedIn() || isUserSessionExpired()))"] > #CC-loginHeader-login').click()
    cy.get('.auth-land-page > :nth-child(1) > .text-center')
    cy.get('.emailLogin > .auth-button-content').click()
    cy.fixture('logindata').then(function (data) {
      this.data = data;
      cy.get('#emailUsername')
      .type(this.data.LoginEmail)
    })
    cy.fixture('logindata').then(function (data) {
      cy.get('#password')
      .type(this.data.LoginPassword)
    })
    cy.get('#loginBtn').click()
    //Error occured here, maybe the tests shouldn't be seperated, let me know if it works.
    //Redirect fails
    cy.get('#CC-loginHeader-logout')
  })
})
```